# Is there a way to debug binary PowerShell Modules with VS Code?

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have written some PowerShell Modules in C#. I know how to debug them in Visual Studio. (With stepping through etc.) Is there a way to debug C# PowerShell Modules in Visual Studio **Code**?

Comment: Since Visual Studio Code supports C# projects, you can also debug C# projects that happen to be PowerShell modules (source code of binary cmdlets).

Comment: But how? Binary Modules are just class libraries. I need a powershell script that calls this library but i don't know how to attach the process so that the breakpoint in the C# code will be hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the debug tab select "Generate C# Assets for Build and Debug"
2. [image: List item]

4. Set breakpoint
5. Start debug and choose the pswh console process
6. Import module and use cmdlet